# What are some good free charts that can be used at ASP.NET MVC website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, charts

What are some good free charts that can be used at ASP.NET MVC website?

The chart should be able to display data from my website. (I need a dynamic chart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RaphaelJs and plugin for charts is very useful. Take a look

http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andrey. But these are javascript, aren't they? How I can pass the data to them through my C# controllers?

Comment: I mean I can use them to display data that exists at the html code (static data). But how I can use them to display my actual dynamic data at the graphs?

Comment: @JimBlum, there are many ways how you can pass data from C# to Javascript. For instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866539/how-to-set-javascript-variables-using-mvc4-with-razor. Just try to find

Comment: Thanks. I have tried g.raphael, but I think is not a very strong solution... It seems that I cannot right the axis labels at my chart, and in addition to show the series names...

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I upvoted it just now. Btw do you know to help me at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097540/weird-chart-maximum-axis-x-value. I am stack with this since yesterday

Answer (score 1):

http://www.highcharts.com/

it's a js lib too; but i think almost lib is js lib.

i know only one solution not js lib
see this http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/10/10/asp-net-mvc-3-beta-built-in-support-for-charts.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, I am developing a system for a company, and highcharts are really expensive for commercial use... Yes, indeed, they are really beautiful, and powerful

Comment: And also thanks for your suggestion about asp.net charts. They are really strong as well, but they are not interactive at all, and also they are somehow not very nice looking compared with others.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I upvoted it just now. Btw do you know to help me at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097540/weird-chart-maximum-axis-x-value. I am stack with this since yesterday