# Use c# variable in Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have c# variable `check` that I want to use in my jquery if condition. But I am getting error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: DGSCRM is not defined

where `DGSCRM` is the value present in my c# variable `check`.

```
@{
    string check = Model.ChangeAddress.ControllerName;
}
<script type=text/javascript>
    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
    if(@check == "DGSCRMAPI")
    {
        $('#logo').hide();
    }
});

</script>
```

Is it the right approach to mix c# and jquery code in views?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set javascript variables using MVC4 with Razor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866539/how-to-set-javascript-variables-using-mvc4-with-razor)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to wrap in `"`

```
if("@check" == "DGSCRMAPI")
```