# Use of C# static string in a typescript class

Tags: c#, typescript

I have an MVC project that is mixed with TypeScript. I need my TypeScript object to obtain a string from my C# class.

I have a c# static class that produces a string from a `StringBuilder`. 
I have a typescript class that I need to be able to access this string.
So in my constructor of the TypeScript class I would like to be able to:

```
this.element.append(MyCSharpStaticString);
```

Is there any way that I can do this ?

Relevant Code

cshtml

```
<div id="GridDiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function () {        
         new Jobber.OrdersGrid($('#GridDiv'), {}).init();

         Q.initFullHeightGridPage($('#GridDiv'));

    });
</script>
```

typescript :

```
export class OrdersGrid extends Serenity.EntityGrid<OrdersRow, any> {

protected getHeaderHtml(reportName) { return OrderHeaderHtml.HtmlHeader(reportName); }

       constructor(container: JQuery) {
            super(container);

          // Finds this element in the code and adds our HTML
          this.element.find('.grid-container').prepend(this.getHeaderHtml(""));

        }
}
```

Comment: are you using `Razor`?

Comment: I see nothing indicating what UI technology you're using, which will influence what answers you get. Someone added the `asp.net-mvc` tag, but it wasn't you, so you should clarify.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan [razor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/razor) is a different tag (not added)... asp.net-mvc is server side, nothing to do with UI... btw you can use asp.net-mvc without razor

Comment: @SantiagoHernández I'm well aware of that, which is why I'm asking the OP to update their question with the appropriate view engine...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set javascript variables using MVC4 with Razor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866539/how-to-set-javascript-variables-using-mvc4-with-razor)

Comment: @DanielA.White no it is strictly a typescript class - there is razor files but the razor file grabs this typescript object - which I need to manipulate the internal of so I can get the desired output. See added code.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan see updated code samples. I am asking Typescript   but if it is possible I can perform the same function via the razor file I am all for it. However I think I would have an issue - because the razor loads once but the ts can refresh and filter client side and may not reproduce my desired result.

Comment: @SantiagoHernández you are correct I did not mention the razor tag on purpose.

Comment: TypeScript just compiles to JavaScript, which is then run in the browser. If you want to get data from the server-side (C#) to the client-side (JavaScript), you'll need to use Razor or some other method (e.g., ajax) to get the information from one to the other. There are many ways of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

If it does return a string you can bind it to your JavaScript method like:

```
<script>
this.element.append('@MyCsharpStaticString()');
</script>
```

Be sure you have included the model to your razor view.

Comment: I think your answer is missing quotes: this.element.append('@MyCsharpStaticString');

Comment: There is nothing in the question that indicates Razor was being used. Is there a reason you assumed that and then edited the question based on your assumption?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan hey, he said he had being using MVC With C# tag, i assumed razor involved. might have been a shot in the dark :)

Comment: @Valkyriee -  while I have a razor file - client side can be updated and so I need the code to be in the client ts .. if it will go using razor I am open to trying it. BTW: cool moniker ..

Comment: @Ken i am afraid mate its impossible without razor, and thanks =)